# How to test a content type with a IContextAwareDefaultFactory

Tags: testing, plone, zope, dexterity, acquisition

We have a Dexterity-based content type that must inherit a field's default value from its parent. We use the following:

In the model:

```xml
<model xmlns="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/schema"
       xmlns:indexer="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/indexer"
       xmlns:form="http://namespaces.plone.org/supermodel/form">
  <schema>
    ...
    <field name="subjects" type="zope.schema.Tuple" indexer:searchable="true">
      ...
      <defaultFactory>my.package.content.default_subjects</defaultFactory>
      ...
    </field>
  </schema>
</model>
```

The factory is declared like this:

```py
from zope.schema.interfaces import IContextAwareDefaultFactory
...
@provider(IContextAwareDefaultFactory)
def default_subjects(context):
    return getattr(context, 'subjects', ())
```

This works fine when running an instance:

```py
(Pdb) context
<MyType at /Plone/folder>
(Pdb) type(context)
<type 'Acquisition.ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper'>
```

But fails when running tests as context is not wrapped:

```py
(Pdb) context
<MyType at test>
(Pdb) type(context)
<class 'my.package.content.MyType'>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: barely related: a [similar problem](https://github.com/collective/collective.newsticker/blob/master/src/collective/newsticker/controlpanel.py#L22-L30) I had some time ago.

Comment: What type of test are you running?
Have you had a look at https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/master/plone/dexterity/tests/test_content.py#L492-L523
From this I gather it depends on your schema properly loaded into the fti.
Maybe this is missing. Depends on your test setup.

Comment: these are the tests: https://github.com/plonegovbr/brasil.gov.agenda/blob/07b978038f5b0da18a66d449ec8f2b1c7e03d560/src/brasil/gov/agenda/tests/test_agendadiaria.py#L80-L98

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everything correctly.
When in code you try to access subjects like that:

```
>>> object.subjects
```

When `subjects` has never been set, the `__getattr__` implementation of Dexterity starts its work. This `__getattr__` magic for missing attributes is implemented by Python. It somehow looses the acquisition wrapper.
After loosing the acquisition wrapper, neither aq_parent nor **parent** continue to work.
In my tests, I was able to circumvent this by calling

```
>>> object.__getattr__('subjects')
```

But this is not satisfactory.

In view code you do not have this problem, because the view does not access the attribute via `object.subjects` at all, so the acquisition context never gets lost.

I'll finish my analysis here, but I noted my findings in a bugreport for plone.dexterity. Maybe you want to provide a minimal test there:
https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/issues/53

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I'll have to wait for more funding in that project; I'll add a reference to this.